# Color margins in VIM

Tags: svn, vim, colors, margins

Does anybody know how I can get diff's color margins in VIM (if it is possible)? I mean something like this: (e.g., in NetBeans: [Netbeans color margins](http://www.picamatic.com/show/2008/11/05/05/39/1308705_147x152.png)). It was very useful when I was working with NetBeans, maybe somebody wrote such useful plugin for VIM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but you can hide one window in vimdiff and the diff colours will remain active. Use 'vim -d file1 file2' and then :hide.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this isn't something natively supported in Vim. There is the [diffchanges plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2158), which might be useful.